# AlwaysEditing : true is not working in dojo datagrid for Date Field

Tags: datagrid, dojo

While setting `alwaysEditing` mode to a date column in dojo datagrid, Only selected row is in `alwaysEditing` mode. How to get all rows for that particular column in `alwaysEditing` mode?
[image]

Here layout for Qualifying Event Date is:

```
{
name : '<b>Qualifying Event Date</b>',
field : 'coveragequalifyingeventdate',
widgetClass : DateTextBox,
widgetProps : {
    readonly : 'readonly'
},
formatter : formatDate,
constraint : {
    formatLength : 'short',
    datePattern : 'MM/dd/yyyy',
    selector : "date"
},
width : '16%',
alwaysEditing : true
```

},